# Grunt with PostCSS does not read and not print file, from folder "src" to "dest"

Tags: gruntjs, autoprefixer, postcss

I installed grunt-postcss and autoprefixer plug-in, but when I try to configure PostCSS with method of the plug-in "[load-grunt-config](https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config)", Autoprefixer and other plug-in, do nothing and do not have alert or error.

This is output from console:

```
$ grunt postcss
Running "postcss:postcss" (postcss) task
Done.
```

When I configure grunt in the standard way, PostCSS it works correctly.

This is my `postcss.js` file, put inside of grunt folder:

```
module.exports = {
  postcss: {
    options: {
      processors: [
        require('autoprefixer')(),
      ]
    },
    dist: {
      src: '<%= project.stylesheets %>/src/main.css',
      dest: '<%= project.stylesheets %>/dest/main.css'
    }
  }
};
```

Instead, with this command `grunt postcss --debug`, the console displays this:

```
Running "postcss:postcss" (postcss) task
[D] Task source: /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-postcss/tasks/postcss.js
Done.
```

Or this command line `$grunt postcss --verbose`, the console display this:

```
$ grunt postcss --verbose
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-bowercopy" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/package.json...OK
Reading bower.json...OK
Parsing bower.json...OK
Loading "bowercopy.js" tasks...OK
+ bowercopy

Registering "grunt-contrib-sass" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-contrib-sass/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-contrib-sass/package.json...OK
Loading "sass.js" tasks...OK
+ sass

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Registering "grunt-modernizr" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-modernizr/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-modernizr/package.json...OK
Loading "modernizr.js" tasks...OK
+ modernizr

Registering "grunt-postcss" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-postcss/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-postcss/package.json...OK
Loading "postcss.js" tasks...OK
+ postcss

Registering "grunt-slim" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-slim/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/mario.montalto/Progetti/start-web-site/frontend/node_modules/grunt-slim/package.json...OK
Loading "slim.js" tasks...OK
+ slim
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ default

Running tasks: postcss

Running "postcss" task

Running "postcss:postcss" (postcss) task
Verifying property postcss.postcss exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: processors=[null], map, diff=false, safe=false, failOnError=false, writeDest

Done.
```

You have no idea how to solve it

Thanks for your help

Mario